# How to mutate a column with if/then in R Data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets suppose if the data is

```
data <- head(iris)
```

How can i create a new column whose values will be derived from `data$Sepal.Length` in a way that if  `data$Sepal.Length` is `equal to or greater than 5`, `value will be 5` and if its `less or equal to 3`, value will be `3`, else values should remain same...
I have tried

```
data %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = case_when(Sepal.Length <=3 ~ '3',Sepal.Length>=5 ~ '5'))
```

But it is giving `NA` to remaining values..

Comment: Look into `ifelse()` or `dplyr::case_when()`

Comment: data %>% mutate(Sepal.Length = case_when(Sepal.Length <=3 ~ '3',Sepal.Length>=5 ~ '5'))

Comment: I have tried this but it gives NA to all others who are not upto 5 and 3 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a basic `case_when` statement:

````
data %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = case_when(
    Sepal.Length <= 3 ~ 3,
    Sepal.Length >= 5 ~ 5,
    TRUE ~ Sepal.Length))

#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1            5         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5            5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6            5         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa```
````